# Freemarker + Java - How to "lookup" a value using key

Tags: java, hashmap, freemarker

In Java, to look up a value using the key, I would use the `.get` method:

```
String value = hashmap.get(key);
```

In Freemarker, apparently `.get` is deprecated or something, because when I try to use it:

```
<#list hash?keys as key>
    <p>${hash.get(key)}</p>
</#list>
```

it returns a null exception:

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
 - Failed at: ${hash.get(key)}  [in template "___.ftl" at line ___, column ___]
----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<#list hash?keys as key>
    <p>${hash[key]}</p>
</#list>
```

See [Retrieving data from a hash](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_hash) section in the Freemarker documentation.

Comment: I can't just blindly get random values; I want to extract one specific key-value pair from the HashMap.

Comment: Then `${hash["yourKey"]}` or `${hash[yourKeyVariable]}`. RTFM.

Comment: Regarding the `#list` example, since 2.3.25 it can be written as `<#list hash as k, v><p>${v}</p></#list>`.